# Ajax no me está pasando por post una variable

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Tengo un evento `onChange` en un selector `html` el cual ejecuta una función. La función se ejecuta bien ya que el `alert` funciona.  El problema es que desde el `php` cuando digo:

`if(isset($_POST['curso'])){}` no entra jamás porque al `POST` nunca le llega esa variable pese a que la función `js` se ejecuta y el valor de la variable curso lo recoge correctamente.

```
function selectorCurso(selector){

    var curso = selector.selectedIndex;
    if (curso != -1 && curso!=0) {
      //alert(i);
      $.ajax({
       type: 'POST',
       data:{curso: curso},
       contentType: false,
       processData: false,
       success: function(data){
        alert(data);
      }
    });
    }
  }
```

Comment: No veo la propiedad [url](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.Ajax/#entry-examples) o al menos en el fragmento que has puesto, aparte que estas enviando un objeto

Answer (score 1):

Como ya te indicaron en los comentarios, falta la url o sea el nombre del archivo a donde vas a enviar tu variable, todo los demás esta correcto, inténtalo de esta forma y comentas si te funcionó.

```js
function selectorCurso(selector){

    var curso = selector.selectedIndex;
   // console.log(curso);
    if (curso != -1 && curso!=0) {
    
       console.log(curso);
       
       $.ajax({
     url: 'tuArchivo.php',
     type: 'POST',
     dataType: '',
     data: {curso: curso},
})
.done(function() {
     console.log("success");
})
       
    }
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="select" name="select" onChange="selectorCurso(this)"> 

<option value="">Seleccicona</option>
<option value="1">Uno</option>
<option value="2">Dos</option>

</select>
```

Comment: Si, el tema es que la url es sobre la misma página, en teoría no es necesario ponerla si es sobre esa misma url. Igualmente he probado poniendo url: "#", que sería la misma y tampoco la pasa.

Comment: `"En teoría"`? Creo que deberías de investigar más acerca de ajax, antes de hacer este tipo de afirmaciones te dejo este [link](https://openclassrooms.com/en/courses/4309491-simplifica-tus-proyectos-con-jquery/4981961-el-metodo-ajax) para que verifiques cómo funciona. Y si lo quieres sobre la misma página no sé porque no usas solamente `PHP`, ya que ajax funciona para ser una petición al servidor en otro archivo diferente, en éste podrás consultar a la Base de Datos para seleccionar, actualizar, borrar, etc,.

Answer (score 0):

Dentro de tu funcion podrias poner asi.

```
    var curso = selector.selectedIndex;
if (curso != -1 && curso!=0) {
  //alert(i);
  $.ajax({
   type: 'POST',
   data:{"curso": curso},
   processData: false,
   success: function(data){
    alert(data);
  }
});
}
```

Observaras que le quitè al attributo "ContenType" y la clave de la data lo pongo en comillas.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta. Si esto también lo he probado sin resultado.